# Velocity trim() method

Tags: velocity, xwiki

For example

> $xcontext.user -> Xwiki.user.trim('Xwiki')

"XWiki." How can I remove the expression?
I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: you want to remove "Xwiki" from String `Xwiki.user`?

Comment: thanks I found the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract the page name (i.e. profile page name) from the current user's reference. It's the best way and you avoid String manipulation:

```
$xcontext.userReference.name
```